# Should extern C wrap each one of my functions?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

Should every function be wrapped by `extern "C"`, or can I just write `extern "C" {` at the beginning of my list-of-functions-definitions and end the block at the very end with `}` ?

Comment: Enclosing the required function prototypes between extern "C" { and } is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

In case you ever want to include the header in a C compiler (as opposed to C++ compiler), you may want to use:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif
 ... list of functions ... 
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
```

Otherwise, both will do the same thing - any function declared within an `extern "C" { ... }` is the same as each function having `extern "C"` as part of its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either. Doing a single extern "C" block is my recommendation. It makes it clear that you mean to be providing a C-style API and avoids the risk of missing it on one function.  If you one day decide to provide a C++ linkage version (or a conditionally compiled version), you'll only have to make the change in one place.